# Remove page number on first level in index

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx

I am using imakeidx to create an index for my recipe book.

I would like to have the index show the following level-wise:

> **Appetizers**
>
> > Recipe 1, pagenumber
> >
> > Recipe 2, pagenumber

What I want, is the index to show the main category without pagenumber, but the actual recipes with pagenumbers. This is a test code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=cat, title=Category, columns=1]
\makeindex[name=type, title=Type of Dish]

\begin{document}
    \index[type]{Casual}    %Want this in bold and no page number
    \index[type]{Quick}     %Want this in bold and no page number
    \index[type]{Formal}    %Want this in bold and no page number
    Appetizers \index[cat]{Appetizers}  %Want this in bold and no page number

    \newpage
    Cauliflower soup \index[cat]{Appetizers!Cauliflower Soup}   \index[type]{Casual!Cauliflower Soup}   %Want this to show as usual with page number

    \newpage
    Drinks  \index[cat]{Drinks} %Want this in bold and no page number

    \newpage
    Lemon Drop \index[cat]{Drinks!Lemon Drop}   %Want this to show as usual with page number


    \printindex[cat]

    \printindex[type]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=cat, title=Category, columns=1]
\makeindex[name=type, title=Type of Dish]

\newcommand\foo[1]{}
\newcommand\textbfz[2]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \index[type]{Casual@\textbfz{Casual}|foo}    %Want this in bold and no page number
    \index[type]{Quick@\textbfz{Quick}|foo}     %Want this in bold and no page number
    \index[type]{Formal@\textbfz{Formal}|foo}    %Want this in bold and no page number
    Appetizers \index[cat]{Apetizers@\textbfz{Appetizers}|foo}  %Want this in bold and no page number

    \newpage
    Cauliflower soup \index[cat]{Apetizers@\textbfz{Appetizers}!Cauliflower Soup} 
   \index[type]{Casual@\textbfz{Casual}|!Cauliflower Soup}   %Want this to show as usual with page number

    \newpage
    Drinks  \index[cat]{Drinks@\textbfz{Drinks}|foo} %Want this in bold and no page number

    \newpage
    Lemon Drop \index[cat]{Drinks@\textbfz{Drinks}!Lemon Drop}   %Want this to show as usual with page number


    \printindex[cat]

    \printindex[type]
\end{document}
```

Comment: your spelling of "appetizers" is somewhat peculiar, not to say inconsistent.  more to the point, what is the point of the period at the end of the category entries?  (not needed, i think.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton spellink? oh never looked at that, was just looking at the fonts:-) the comma yes not really needed could replace `@\textbf` by `@\zz` defined by `\newcommand\zz[2]{\textbf{#1}}`  then `#2` would gobble the comma.

Comment: @barbarabeeton better?

Comment: Just one question, why is `column=1` needed?

Comment: @Ahana I didn't even see it, it was just in the original file.

Comment: Oh, that was me playing around with it. Apparently it seem to not work when I have 2 columns. Seeing it's going to be a recipe book I'd prefer to have 2 columns. (had it there when I tried before I asked the question)

Any ideas on how to get it to work with 2 columns/standard setting for column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18109/discussion-between-ahana-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: @Ahana nothing in that code is related to columns it just sets teh font for the heading, if you have 2 col index then it should work fine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- much better.  thanks.

Comment: I added this between the Cauliflower Soup and Drinks: `\newpage
   Chicken soup \index[cat]{Soup@\textbfz{Soup}!Chicken Soup}` and now it looks like this: [http://i.imgur.com/FO25DZL.png?1]